# How can I find which object in ASP.NET can't be serialized?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, serialization

I'm getting the following error in my application:

> Unable to serialize the session state.
>   In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode,
>   ASP.NET will serialize the session
>   state objects, and as a result
>   non-serializable objects or
>   MarshalByRef objects are not
>   permitted. The same restriction
>   applies if similar serialization is
>   done by the custom session state store
>   in 'Custom' mode.

The stack trace isn't providing any good information on which object is not able to serialize. Is there a good way to find the problem child?

Edit:
I've found the issue, I was trying to serialize a Linq statement(not executed). But I'll try an choose an answer that would have best solved this issue.

Comment: It shouldn't actually be that hard to come up with a function that recursively finds all references of an object and determine whether the anything is not marked as [Serializable].

Comment: How do would you know which ones would be serialized and added to the session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really, you should mainly be storing your **own** state data / objects (ideally modelled as DTO classes), in which case the answer is: any *you* mark as `[Serializable]` or `ISerializable`. You shouldn't be adding raw UI controls or other unknown objects to session-state. In particular, for reasons [like this](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/11/state-assassins-with-experience-of.html), which had a major performance impact on an app the other day.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I thought I was storing an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>, the problem was I was only storing the Linq clause, but in other places I was first using the ToList() extension to enumerate.

Answer (score 2):

MbUnit (now Gallio) has an Assert.IsSerializable() test that could come in handy here.

Comment: I did create a unit test which did a binary serialization on the class I thought was the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to serialize the object, and inspect the `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException` that's thrown when it's not serializable. It should tell you which member or parent of the object can't be serialized.

Example code:

```
var f = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
f.Serialize(new System.IO.MemoryStream(), yourObject);
```

Comment: Blast from the past here. But yea, I feel like I've now seen more details in that exception than when I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do in a similar situation is to look at every object the Session references and check it for the presence of the Serializable attribute (or that the object implements ISerialzable interface).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the culprit types which fire the serialization exception through .net framework code debugging. At least that's what I did.