# Asp.net State Server Unable to Serialize Session State

Tags: asp.net, stateserver

I am using StateServer session,made all object [Serializable] ,still getting error.What was the problem?

Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

**Here's the code...getting error on Response.Redirect("common/TicklerDisplay**

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Try
        SetOffset()
        strUserName = txtEmaillAdd.Text.Trim
        strPassword = txtPassword.Text.Trim



        Dim strSubscriptionLogin() As String = CCommon.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SubscriptionManagement")).Split("/")
        If strSubscriptionLogin.Length = 2 Then
            If strSubscriptionLogin(0) = strUserName And strSubscriptionLogin(1) = strPassword Then
                Session("DomainID") = 1
                Session("UserContactID") = 1
                Session("PagingRows") = 20
                Session("DateFormat") = "DD/MONTH/YYYY"

                Response.Redirect("Service/frmSerNav.htm", False)
                Exit Sub

            End If
        End If

        If sb_GetDomainUser() = False Then
            Session.Abandon()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ExceptionModule.ExceptionPublish(ex, Session("DomainID"), Session("UserContactID"), Request)
        Response.Write(ex)
        Session.Abandon()
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    If GetQueryStringVal("From") = "Help" Then
        Dim HelpURL As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HelpURL")

        HelpURL = HelpURL & "?a=" & objCommon.Encrypt(Session("AccessID")) & "&pageurl=" & CCommon.ToString(GetQueryStringVal("pageurl"))
        Response.Redirect(HelpURL)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Response.Redirect("common/TicklerDisplay.aspx?ClientMachineUTCTimeOffset=" & txtOffset.Text.Trim)
        'HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
    End If
    'Response.Redirect("include/frmMenu.aspx")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please check that the datatype of data-members which are set as serializable? As some of the datatypes might not be serialized

Comment: Some code please. Not all object even with Serializable, can be serialized, like the Dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Stacktrace where it throws the error. It should tell you excatly which object it cant serialize. As per the comments above, not all object can be serialized.

See: [How can I find which object in ASP.NET can't be serialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772854/how-can-i-find-which-object-in-asp-net-cant-be-serialized)

Comment: FYI, I have myself, found a workaround if I indeed needed to serialize an object.. de-serialize it later, using a stateserver. If you really need to do this, maybe start a new question, Re, how to serialize non serializable objects... don;t think it appropriate to add it to this question.